# How to calculate the difference in days between two dates in Python using the time module?

Tags: python, date, time

When I am passing dates like 15-05-2020 and 16-06-2020 it gives 2 but I want 32 or 33

```py
    date1 = v_parking_in_date = input('Please Enter the Parking Start Date in dd-mm-yyyy format :')
    date2 = v_parking_out_date = input('Please Enter the Parking Completion Date in dd-mm-yyyy format :')
    date_1 = time.mktime(time.strptime(date1, "%d-%m-%Y"))
    date_2 = time.mktime(time.strptime(date2, "%d-%m-%Y"))
    d = (date_2 - date_1)
```

Comment: You should be getting the the number of seconds between those two dates.  I don't see how you could possibly be getting 2 as the result.  If you want the number of days difference, divide the result by the number of seconds in a day.

Comment: it is getting subtracted date to date, month to month,year to year that's y

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [datetime](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/datetime.html) module to compute the delta between the two dates :

```
import datetime as dt
import time

date1 = input('Please Enter the Parking Start Date in dd-mm-yyyy format :')
date2 = input('Please Enter the Parking Completion Date in dd-mm-yyyy format :')
date_1 = dt.date.fromtimestamp(time.mktime(time.strptime(date1, "%d-%m-%Y")))
date_2 = dt.date.fromtimestamp(time.mktime(time.strptime(date2, "%d-%m-%Y")))
d = date_2 - date_1 # datetime.timedelta(days=32)
```

First, by using `time.mktime` you are getting the value of seconds since the Epoch for your date. Then by using [`datetime.date.fromtimestamp`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.fromtimestamp) you are creating a [`date`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/datetime.html#date-objects) object from this value in seconds.

Answer (score 0):

If possible, do not use the time module for this task, since you do not need to take into account hours, minutes or seconds.

Using the [date](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#date-objects) class from the [datetime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html) module is probably a better idea:

```py
from datetime import date

def difference_in_days(dmy_date_1, dmy_date_2):
  # Converts the given dates to yyyy-mm-dd format (ISO 8601),
  #   so that date.fromisoformat() can work with them.
  ymd_date_1 = "-".join(reversed(dmy_date_1.split("-")))
  ymd_date_2 = "-".join(reversed(dmy_date_2.split("-")))
  # Creates actual date objects from our string values.
  date_1 = date.fromisoformat(ymd_date_1)
  date_2 = date.fromisoformat(ymd_date_2)
  # Subtracting a date object from another gives a timedelta object,
  #   which has a useful .days attribute.
  return abs(date_1 - date_2).days
```

Test:

```
>>> difference_in_days("15-05-2020", "16-06-2020")
32
```

Comment: by using date it's very easy, i was only looking for using time module. Thanks for ur answer